# How can I run a function only for a period of time? javascript

Tags: javascript, function, set, timeout

So I have made an application for fun and practice... and in the application I kind of need a function that only runs for a certain time like 1min or 15 min and then it restart to the main stats.

And I noticed I dont know how to make run a function for a certain time and then it  come back again.

after i have search and tried a couple of hours This is what I have made :

```js
function start() {
  let div = document.createElement('div');
  div.id = 'div'

  let button1 = document.createElement('button');
  button1.type = 'button';
  button1.className = 'btn btn-warning col-5 mt-1 mr-5';
  button1.innerHTML = 'I did it!';
  button1.id = 'button1';
  button1.onclick = function didit() {
    alert(' I did it!')
    // earn exp
    // next img
  }

  let button2 = document.createElement('button');
  button2.type = 'button';
  button2.className = 'btn btn-warning col-5 mt-1';
  button2.innerHTML = 'Não Consegui :(';
  button2.id = 'button2';
  button2.onclick = function giveup() {
    alert('giveup')
    //earn 0 exp
    //next img
  }

  div.appendChild(button1);
  div.appendChild(button2);

  let button = document.getElementById('button');

  button.before(div);
  button.remove();

  // restart

  setTimeout(restart(), 1 * 60 * 1000);
}

function restart() {
  let button3 = document.createElement('button');
  button3.type = 'button';
  button3.className = 'btn btn-warning col-12 mt-1 mr-5';
  button3.onclick = function start();
  button3.innerHTML = 'Start';
  button3.id = 'button';

  let div = document.getElementById('div');

  div.before(button);
  div.remove();
}
```

```html
<button type="button" class="btn btn-warning col-12 mt-1 mr-5 ml-0" onclick="start()" id="button">Start</button>
```

I think it should be something like this. but I'm getting an error :/
Sorry if it is too big.

Comment: The first argument to `setTimeout()` should be the function name, not a call to the function.

Comment: hi, interesting, what error are you getting? perhaps pass the function in `setTimeout(restart, delay)` instead of calling the function immediately with `restart()` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout

Comment: `setTimeout` doesn't run a function for a period of time. It waits that period and then runs the function.

Comment: What you should do is save the time in a variable when the user starts the game. The event listeners can then check whether the current time is less than 15 minutes since the start time. If it's after the timeout, they don't do anything.

Comment: You could also use `setTimeout()` to run a function that disables the buttons.

Comment: well what i tried to make like a kind of a loop, trying to replace the button for 2 buttons and after a while come the " start button " again. So what I did was to replace the start button to 2 buttons, and after a while setTimeout to bring the 1 button again as in the start.
Make sense?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, [setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout) accepts function and a delay time in milliseconds as parameters. 
In Javascript you can pass functions as any other variable just by the name, having:

```
let secondsBeforeRestart = 60
setTimeout(restart, secondsBeforeRestart * 1000);
```

Also, not sure what the `1 * 60 * 1000` is all about. Just have a param that stores seconds. That way you can always understand the code. Even after 6 months.

Comment: 1 * 60 * 1000 would be just to pass milliseconds to 1 minute, and foward I would let it dynamic!

Comment: but I think I did it! All I did, it was instead of trying to call  function restart(){ .....}  inside setTimeout doing "setTimeout( restart() , secondsBeforeRestart * 1000)"

 I  literally put it inside doing setTimeout( function restart() {.......} , secondsBeforeRestart * 1000)

Comment: And before I was getting an error inside restart function, where I did button3.onclick = function start(); trying to call start() function trying to make a loop, but I commented and it worked it, calling itself